# iPhone removeFromSuperview troubles

Tags: iphone

I am using a tab bar with a button that calls the current view and does a flip animation to reload it. Once it reloads it performs some operations that alter the view slightly from the last time it was visible.

While the view is flipping, you are able to see the previous view below it.

When I use:

```
[menuView removeFromSuperview];
```

the view flips the superview is black underneath like I want but the:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

does not fire. My new flipped view is unchanged.

What I want is for the back to be black while the view is flipping and the viewDidLoad to fire.

Any help?

Comment: Would you mind adding some more code? I'm having hard time trying to figure out what is going on here from your description. I will say that viewDidLoad is only called once, when the view is first loaded. You may want to use something like viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear instead.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` may be called more than once over the lifetime of the controller (for example, if the view was unloaded due to memory constraints). But it's the callback that tells you that the view property was nil, and now has been loaded (from a nib, by `loadView`, etc.). Removing it from its superview and re-adding it wouldn't cause it to be called again.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised viewDidLoad was called more than once either way. Have you tried putting the code to update the view in [viewWillAppear](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16) instead?

Comment: I used viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear and the view comes up black.